# Remove identical IN Subselect in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a simple table that contains references between items. In another table, the items are grouped together. Each item can be in any number of groups.

example:

```
Items:
ItemID  | ItemName
------------------
1       | Item 1
2       | Item 2
3       | Item 3
4       | Item 4

Groups:
GroupID | ItemID
-----------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 4
2       | 2
2       | 3

References:
RefSourceItem   | RefTargetItem
-------------------------------
1               | 2
2               | 3
2               | 4
```

Now I want to select all References in a certain group, that is, source AND target are both in the same group. The statement I came up with is this:

```
SELECT * FROM References 
WHERE RefSourceItem IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = 1)
AND   RefTargetItem IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = 1)
```

What I find a bit problematic is that I have two identical subselects.

My question:
Is there a better way to restrict two columns to the same subselect?

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to write this using joins, but as you can see, there is still some duplication as you have to check both tables. Joins may be more efficient, depending on your environment, could be worth trying out.

```
SELECT              *
FROM                References AS R
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups AS G1 ON R.RefSourceItem = G.ItemID AND G.GroupID = 1
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups AS G2 ON R.RefTargetItem = G2.ItemID AND G2.GroupID = 1
WHERE               (G1.ItemID IS NOT NULL OR G2.ItemID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: At least this would work.  I fail to see how it is an improvement on the OP's query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes you're correct, as I have mentioned, just providing an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```
SELECT r.RefSourceItem, r.RefTargetItem 
FROM References r
JOIN Groups g 
  ON g.ItemID IN (r.RefSourceItem, r.RefTargetItem) AND g.GroupID = 1
GROUP BY r.RefSourceItem, r.RefTargetItem 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```